# Renaming a variable name in r

Tags: r

I want to rename a column but, after running the code without errors, it doesn't change. The second variable of the data frame is 'Latest Name' and I want to change it to 'Name'.

Then I run:

```
rename(companies_names_industries, Name = 'Latest Name')
```

As you see below, the name has changed:

[image]

But then I check it again listing the variables names.

```
names(companies_names_industries)
```

And It is still the same, as you can see here:

[image]

Why does this happen? And how can I definitely change the name of the variable?

Comment: `companies_names_industries <- rename(companies_names_industries, Name = 'Latest Name')`

Answer (score 1):

you have to assign the data.frame to an object. your code will run but doesn't store it.

try:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- rename(companies_names_industries, Name = 'Latest Name')
names(df)
```